# how do you scan if there is something active in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

stage3 is after stage 2. I want to know how to tell if `mouseIsPressed` and stage2 is active.

I've already tried the `if(mouseIsPressed&&stage2===true){so on}`

```
var hp=100;
var name=["boromon","telemon","heptamon","coromon"];
var boromon={
eyecolor:"blue",
skincolor:[0,0,255],
abilitys:["beam of life","blinding bite","stare strike"]
};
var enemy=[hp,name[1]];
fill(255, 0, 0);
text(name[0]+" wants to be your freind"+"                               click to accept",10,10);
var currentCharacter=[];


fill(41, 23, 23);
text(currentCharacter,10,10);
var stage2=function(){
background(255, 0, 0);
text(currentCharacter+" is now your freind                          click to continue",10,10);

};

var stage3=function(){
background(0, 174, 255);
var star=getImage("space/star");
image(star,10,10);
image(star,10,10);
image(star,10,10);
image(star,10,10);
};


draw=function() {
    if(mouseIsPressed)
{currentCharacter=name[0];}

if (mouseIsPressed){
    stage2();

if(mouseIsPressed){stage3();}
}
};
```

I want to push the mouse and the output to be different each time

Comment: You need to search for references for "javascript, event listeners".  Rather than having a variable that says if the mouse is pressed or not, you setup your page to "listen" for the event of when a user presses the mouse, and process accordingly.

Comment: I recommend to have a look at the MDN guides, especially https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events .

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `mouseIsPressed` - make it lile so:

```
var mouseIsPressed = 0;
document.body.onmousedown = () => ++mouseIsPressed;
document.body.onmouseup = () => --mouseIsPressed;
```

Comment: thanks but i need to find out how to see what page its on, such as stage2 or stage3